# Cisco ASA L2TP remote-access VPN with addresses assigned by DHCP

Tags: cisco-asa, dhcp, l2tp

I have an ASA with a working Cisco VPN Client configuration set up.  I am trying to phase out the Cisco VPN Client, initially in favour of L2TP.

The Cisco Client policy has end-users fetch their address from a DHCP server which doles out a specific subnet.  Wanting to stick to that subnet, because there are nat-exempt and hairpin-nat rules already in place for it, that forward the clients on to other sites.

I have also got a `split-tunnel-network-list` applied.

I can get the end-user L2TP client to connect, no problem at all.  I can get the L2TP client to fetch its addresses from the DHCP server (confirmed via server lease info and via `show vpn-sessiondb`).  However, no traffic passes because the client either never receives or discards the static routes normally applied by the `split-tunnel-network-list`, in favour of an incorrect route.

If I take the `dhcp-server` out of the `tunnel-group` and use an arbitrary `ip local pool` instead, the L2TP client adds the routes as per the `split-tunnel-network-list` ACL, but then won't pass the traffic because the nat-exempt and hairpin-nat does not match the `ip local pool` range.

If take the `dhcp-server` out of the tunnel-group and use the same subnet as the DHCP server in the `ip local pool` (i.e. to match the nat rules), the L2TP client goes back to not adding the routes.

I *know* I can double-up all the nat-exempt and hairpin-nat rules so there are rules for both the `dhcp-server` subnet and the `ip local pool`, but I don't see why I should *have* to.

**What is stopping the routes being supplied/received/applied properly between the ASA and the L2TP clients?**

*(sanitised, hopefully-pertinent config below — there are far more VPNs and sites in the actual config, hence the desire not to change the subnet)*

```
interface Redundant1
 nameif OUTSIDE
 security-level 0
 ip address p.e.e.r 255.255.255.0
!
interface Redundant2.1
 vlan 1
 nameif INSIDE
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.21.0.10 255.255.240.0
!

object network VPN_CLIENT_LAN
 subnet 172.21.255.0 255.255.255.0
object network HAIRPIN_NAT_IP
 host 172.21.0.1
object network IDONTWANTTHIS_POOL_LAN
 subnet 192.168.254.0 255.255.255.0

object-group network HEADOFFICE_LAN
 network-object 172.21.0.0 255.255.240.0
object-group network BRANCHOFFICE_LAN
 network-object 172.21.16.0 255.255.240.0
object-group network DATACENTRE1_LAN
 network-object 172.27.0.0 255.255.0.0
object-group network DATACENTRE2_LAN
 network-object 172.28.0.0 255.255.0.0
object-group network SITE_LANS
 group-object HEADOFFICE_LAN
 group-object BRANCHOFFICE_LAN
 group-object DATACENTRE1_LAN
 group-object DATACENTRE2_LAN
object-group network CLIENT_VPN_ACCESSIBLE_NETWORKS
 group-object SITE_LANS

access-list CRY_RA_OUTSIDE extended permit ip any object VPN_CLIENT_LAN

access-list ACL_CLIENT_VPN_SPLIT_TUNNEL extended permit ip object-group CLIENT_VPN_ACCESSIBLE_NETWORKS object VPN_CLIENT_LAN 

ip local pool IDONTWANTTHIS_POOL 192.168.254.1-192.168.254.254 mask 255.255.255.255

nat (OUTSIDE,OUTSIDE) source dynamic VPN_CLIENT_LAN HAIRPIN_NAT_IP destination static CLIENT_VPN_ACCESSIBLE_NETWORKS CLIENT_VPN_ACCESSIBLE_NETWORKS
nat (INSIDE,INSIDE) source static HEADOFFICE_LAN HEADOFFICE_LAN destination static VPN_CLIENT_LAN VPN_CLIENT_LAN no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (INSIDE,INSIDE) source static HEADOFFICE_LAN HEADOFFICE_LAN destination static SITE_LANS SITE_LANS no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (INSIDE,OUTSIDE) source static HEADOFFICE_LAN HEADOFFICE_LAN destination static IDONTWANTTHIS_POOL_LAN IDONTWANTTHIS_POOL_LAN no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (INSIDE,OUTSIDE) source static HEADOFFICE_LAN HEADOFFICE_LAN destination static VPN_CLIENT_LAN VPN_CLIENT_LAN no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (INSIDE,OUTSIDE) source static HEADOFFICE_LAN HEADOFFICE_LAN destination static SITE_LANS SITE_LANS no-proxy-arp route-lookup
!
nat (INSIDE,OUTSIDE) after-auto source dynamic HEADOFFICE_LAN interface destination static ANY_IPV4 ANY_IPV4

crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES128-SHA1-TRANSPORT esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES128-SHA1-TRANSPORT mode transport    

crypto dynamic-map CRY_RA_OUTSIDE 10 match address CRY_RA_OUTSIDE
crypto dynamic-map CRY_RA_OUTSIDE 10 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5
crypto dynamic-map CRY_RA_OUTSIDE 10 set security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto dynamic-map CRY_RA_OUTSIDE 10 set reverse-route
crypto dynamic-map CRY_RA_OUTSIDE 20 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES128-SHA1-TRANSPORT
crypto dynamic-map CRY_RA_OUTSIDE 20 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
crypto dynamic-map CRY_RA_OUTSIDE 20 set reverse-route
crypto map CRY_L2L_OUTSIDE 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic CRY_RA_OUTSIDE
crypto map CRY_L2L_OUTSIDE interface OUTSIDE
crypto isakmp identity address

group-policy GPO_CISCO_CLIENT_VPN internal
group-policy GPO_CISCO_CLIENT_VPN attributes
 dns-server value 172.21.1.1 172.21.1.2
 dhcp-network-scope 172.21.255.0
 vpn-idle-timeout 1800
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value ACL_CLIENT_VPN_SPLIT_TUNNEL
 default-domain value foo.local

group-policy GPO_L2TP_CLIENT_VPN internal
group-policy GPO_L2TP_CLIENT_VPN attributes
 dhcp-network-scope 172.21.255.0
 vpn-tunnel-protocol l2tp-ipsec
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value ACL_CLIENT_VPN_SPLIT_TUNNEL
 default-domain value foo.local
 intercept-dhcp enable
 nac-settings none

tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup general-attributes
 authentication-server-group (OUTSIDE) AAA_WORKING_RADIUS_SETUP
 default-group-policy GPO_L2TP_CLIENT_VPN
 dhcp-server 172.21.1.1
 dhcp-server 172.21.1.2    
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
 isakmp keepalive threshold 120 retry 2
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ppp-attributes
 no authentication chap
 authentication ms-chap-v2

tunnel-group GPO_CISCO_CLIENT_VPN type remote-access
tunnel-group GPO_CISCO_CLIENT_VPN general-attributes
 authentication-server-group (OUTSIDE) AAA_WORKING_RADIUS_SETUP
 default-group-policy GPO_CISCO_CLIENT_VPN 
 dhcp-server 172.21.1.2
 dhcp-server 172.21.1.1
tunnel-group GPO_CISCO_CLIENT_VPN ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
```

*(The route that is added when using the `dhcp-server` config, where `p.e.e.r` is the outside IP of the ASA)*:

```
172.21.0.0     mask 255.255.0.0    gw p.e.e.r  if 172.21.255.1
```

*(The routes that are added when using the arbitrary `address-pool IDONTWANTTHIS_POOL` config)*:

```
172.21.0.0     mask 255.255.240.0  gw on-link  if 192.168.254.1
172.21.16.0    mask 255.255.240.0  gw on-link  if 192.168.254.1
172.27.0.0     mask 255.255.0.0    gw on-link  if 192.168.254.1
172.28.0.0     mask 255.255.0.0    gw on-link  if 192.168.254.1
192.168.254.0  mask 255.255.255.0  gw p.e.e.r  if 192.168.254.1
```